# get coordinates of the character in a span in context of the container div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the example where i want coordinates of the word "standard" that is in second span using javascript/jquery.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <span>Some text is here</span>
        <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</span>
        <span>Some text is here too.</span>
        <span>Some text is here too.</span>
        <span>Some text is here too.</span>
        <span>Some text is here too.</span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    position: relative;
    padding: 100px;
}
span{
     position:relative;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P7rs4/1/

Comment: What do you mean by 'coordinates'? What is the required result for the word 'standard' in this example?

Comment: yes, x and y coordinates

Comment: "standard" is just an example i have given. I want to know any particular word's left,top(x,y) position that is in the span.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the coordinates of a word, it must be wrapped in an element first

```
$('.container').html(function(_, html) {
    return html.replace('standard', '<span class="standard">standard</span>');
});
```

Then you get the `offset()` position of that element relative to the document, or relative to the parent element with `position()`

```
var position = $('.standard').offset();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/P7rs4/2/)

Comment: I think this is the solution, but adding span is something I don't prefer, is there any other way we can do this?

Comment: I don't think so, as without it, the word will be just a `textNode` which doesn't have the properties that you need to find the coordinates.

Comment: You probably could get the coordinates of a textNode, but the textNode would contain more than just that word, and it would be hard and not very accurate. It's a lot easier to just wrap it in a span.

Comment: You could also wrap it and remove it again after getting the position.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Edited.

```
var field = $('.container > span').filter(function (){
        return $(this).text().contains('standard');
});

var position = field.position();
```

Basically it will get all elements with text standard, so it could be more than one. so real case solution would be to loop the result and then get the position.

Comment: that will return position of the span, i dont want it. I want position of any particular word

Comment: can you do it on fiddle?

Comment: sorry I don't have any fiddle or similar account.